# jquery replace text in nested list

Tags: jquery, search, text, replace

```
<ul class="playlist">
    <li class="track_name">$name1
        <ul>
            <li class="play"><a class="play_link" href="$url">play</a></li>
            <li class="download"><a href="download.php?id=$url">download</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li> ... more tracks here
</ul>
<ul class="playlist">
... more playlists here
```

Given a dynamically generated unordered nested lists, what is the easiest way to replace text 'play' in `<li class="play">` with $name1?

I've done the following:

```
var val = $('.play').closest('.track_name').clone().children().remove().end().text();
$('.play_link').text(val);
```

This gives me all track_names, but can't figure out how to get just the relevant track name.

TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a function into `.text()`, which will allow you to set the text of all of the `.play` elements:

```
$('.play a').text(function(i, v) {
    return $(this).closest('.track_name').clone().children().remove().end().text();
});
```

[Code Example](http://jsfiddle.net/g8aVv/)

Comment: I think it should be `$('.play a')`

Comment: Works great! Would it somehow be possible to hide that parent `<li class="track_name">$name1` without disrupting the function?

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the selected one to have a `selected` class on click and then use that class to get the selected one: (or do whatever else)

Something like:

```
<li class="track_name">
    <span class="text">$name1</span>
    <ul>
        <li class="play"><a class="play_link" href="$url">play</a></li>
        <li class="download"><a href="download.php?id=$url">download</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>

$(".track_name").on("click", function(e) {
    $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected")
        .find('.play_link').text($(".selected .text").text());
});
```